# 1004: application defined or object defined error (2nd Loop)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I'm writing some vb to export data from access to excel.  Once passed to excel, I use code to format one spreadsheet in the workbook, then save and close the file.  It is supposed to loop through this code several times.  When I execute the code, it creates the first itteration of the spreadsheet, but on the second pass it returns a 1004: application defined or object defined error.  Been searching for a solution and cannot find.  Help please?

===============================================

## Code is below

On Error GoTo errorhandler

```
Dim strtable As String
Dim strworksheetpath As String
Dim pickersct As Integer
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSh As Excel.Worksheet

pickersct = 1
Me.Text7 = 1

Do Until pickersct > Me.Text1

    Me.Text7.Requery
    strworksheetpath = "D:\My Documents\Deliverable" & pickersct & ".xls"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "qry_pickers_Picks_Export", strworksheetpath

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\My Documents\deliverable" & pickersct & ".xls")
    Set xlSh = xlWB.Sheets("qry_pickers_Picks_Export")

        Sheets("qry_pickers_Picks_Export").Activate 'Error occurs after this line
        Sheets("qry_pickers_Picks_Export").Range("H2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=1,-1,0)"
        Sheets("qry_pickers_Picks_Export").Range("I2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=1,-1,0)"
        Sheets("qry_pickers_Picks_Export").Range("J2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]+RC[-1]"
        Sheets("qry_pickers_Picks_Export").Range("J2").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
            Formula1:="=1"

    xlWB.Save
    xlWB.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

    pickersct = pickersct + 1
    Me.Text7 = Me.Text7 + 1
Loop

errorHandlerExit:
  Exit Sub

errorhandler:
  MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & "; Description: " & Err.Description
  Resume errorHandlerExit
```

Comment: At what line you get this error?

Comment: its advised not to use .select but use other methods. you can use the following code to do 2 steps in 1: `xlSh.Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=1,-1,0)"` plus you define xlSh but then don't use it, as in the code in my comment I included this.

Answer (score 0):

Recorded VBA from Excel usually doesn't work directly in Access. I'm surprised it runs for the first iteration.

`Sheets` or `ActiveCell` don't work without reference to the Excel application object. It is best to assign objects and always work with them.

- Replace `Sheets("qry_pickers_Picks_Export")` with `xlSh`.
- Don't use `.Select` and `ActiveCell.`
- Specify the range, and set its properties, e.g.
  `xlSh.Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=1,-1,0)"`